# Sending a Future as a message between Akka actors

Tags: scala, akka, future

I'm invoking a web service that returns an `Option[Future[String]]` inside an Akka actor. Now I need to spin a new child actor and pass this `Option[Future[String]]` and stop the actor.In the child actor I want to wait for the future to complete so that I can do something with the result. Is it okay to pass Futures around Akka actors?

Comment: My gut feeling is that, as long as they are on the same VM there shouldn't be a problem. Passing it to a remote actor, though, will probably cause problems

Comment: Yes, this is inside the same JVM. I feel the same but I want to confirm it.

Comment: Why not just call that future in the child actor?  And actually you can use `future.onComplete` and other Future methods. Anyway, passing simple,immutable, serilizable `message` is always a good idea, if you really want pipe the result of future, you can use `akka.pattern.pipe` to pipe the result while future is completed.

Comment: I'm quite sure futures are completely thread safe. You could even await their completion in 2 different threads at the same time. Although of course you shouldn't use await in an actor.

Comment: Another option might be to use an `onSuccess` callback on the `Future` and send the message to the other actor there. The other actor would then receive a String directly.

Comment: @SpiderPig - when you say "you shouldn't use await in an actor" how else can I handle it. For example, in this case I'm calling a web service inside an actor and I need the result that I can then push downstream.

Comment: Await is used pause the current thread until the future is finished. But you should never pause the thread inside an actor. The normal way to handle the return value of a future is to invoke e.g. map, flatMap, foreach, onComplete, onSuccess, etc. or use for comprehension since that is just syntactic sugar for map, flatMap and foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning: Not compiled, see doc.akka.io if in doubt.

```
import akka.pattern.pipeTo
def receive = {
  case something =>
    webService.call() foreach { _ pipeTo context.actorOf(Props[Child]) }
}
```

The idea is that you do not need the child actor if the web service doesn't return anything (None), and if it returns Some(future) you send the result of that Future to the newly created child actor. The newly created child actor can then self-terminate once it receives the result of the webservice call.